# Chain 2 @Query commands in Room

Tags: android, android-room

I am building an Android app as a side project using Room Persistence Library and I came across a small problem: I'd like to chain two `@Query` commands in Room like so:

`"UPDATE table SET bool = 0 WHERE bool = 1"` and `"UPDATE table SET bool = 1 WHERE id = :objId"` where `objId` is given as a parameter in the Dao.

The first one is to reset all of the `bool` variables for all objects and update `bool` for only one object.

I'm trying to chain those 2 `@Query` commands in a single `@Query` command.

I searched a lot on the internet without luck. I'm not sure if this can be done in an easier way, and if it can be, please do post the correct way to do it. I'm a beginner in Room and every help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What's the issue of having 2 methods in your Dao class? say`resetAllData()` and `resetDataWithId(...)`? Then you can call them in which order you prefer, thus as a result having the chain effect.

Comment: Yeah I could do that. But it's easier to chain them, if it can be done